# peticiones duplicadas en angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

por que sucede esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el metodo que uso, pero genero dos peticiones, el motodo se ejecuta en el onInit

```
verificarDeuda(){
this.servicioEstudiantil.getDataGeneral('Deudores/'+this.dataParaSolvencia.cuenta).subscribe((data:any)=>{
  const dataSource = {      
    deudanor:data.data.deudores.filter(deuda => deuda.monto!=0 && deuda.monto!='' && deuda.monto!=null),
    deudaex:data.data.deudoresExcel.filter(deuda => deuda.monto!=0 && deuda.monto!='' && deuda.monto!=null),        
   // totalDeuda: this.concordia.monto(data.data.deudores,data.data.deudoresExcel, 'monto')    
   }

  
  console.log('DD NORMAL: ', dataSource.deudanor.length);
  console.log('DD EX:',  dataSource.deudaex);
  //console.log('MONTO:',dataSource.totalDeuda );

}, (err)=>{
  console.log('err0r');
  
  })
}
```

a que se debe esto? (Angular 10)

Comment: Revisa el método de las peticiones en la pestaña de red del navegador y confirma si la primera de cada una es de tipo `OPTIONS`. Si es así entonces es normal.

Comment: Request Method: OPTIONS, si, ambas lo son

Comment: Puedes leer acerca de `preflight request` para entender mejor el tema https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: bien, pero tiene solución? veo que se repiten sin motivo aparente

Comment: Es que no es un problema. Eso es normal, no hay nada que corregirle.

Comment: muchas gracias, no debo preocuparme entonces